# How to kill a running process using ansible?

Tags: process, ansible, kill, ansible-2.x, kill-process

I have an ansible playbook to kill running processes and works great most of the time!, however, from time to time we find processes that just can't be killed so, "wait_for" gets to the timeout, throws an error and it stops the process.

The current workaround is to manually go into the box, use "kill -9" and run the ansible playbook again so I was wondering if there is any way to handle this scenario from ansible itself?, I mean, I don't want to use kill -9 from the beginning but I maybe a way to handle the timeout?, even to use kill -9 only if process hasn't been killed in 300 seconds? but what would be the best way to do it?

These are the tasks I currently have:

```
- name: Get running processes
  shell: "ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -w {{ PROCESS }} | awk '{print $2}'"
  register: running_processes

- name: Kill running processes
  shell: "kill {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ running_processes.stdout_lines }}"

- name: Waiting until all running processes are killed
  wait_for:
    path: "/proc/{{ item }}/status"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ running_processes.stdout_lines }}"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use shell only when shell functionality is required.

        command: "kill {{ item }}"

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You could ignore errors on `wait_for` and register the result to force kill failed items:

```
- name: Get running processes
  shell: "ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -w {{ PROCESS }} | awk '{print $2}'"
  register: running_processes

- name: Kill running processes
  shell: "kill {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ running_processes.stdout_lines }}"

- wait_for:
    path: "/proc/{{ item }}/status"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ running_processes.stdout_lines }}"
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: killed_processes

- name: Force kill stuck processes
  shell: "kill -9 {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ killed_processes.results | select('failed') | map(attribute='item') | list }}"
```

Comment: Can I use this in a bog post? (with link back to this reply) @Eric

Comment: Btw, this will wait for {{timeout}} seconds per process, so 5 processes will result in 5*{{timeout}}. I wonder if this can be improved via async..

Comment: Can you please explain `"{{ killed_processes.results | select('failed') | map(attribute='item') | list }}"` ? I am new to Ansible and I am looking for a set of tasks that would kill a set of processes reliably.

Comment: Instead of using the long ps command `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -w {{ PROCESS }} | awk '{print $2}'` you can do it all with ps `ps -C {{ PROCESS }} -o pid=` This will only print the pid of the command PROCESS. the "-C {{ PROCESS  }}" is equivalent to the first 3 commands in the pipe. the "-o pid=" prints only the PID numbers without the header. An even easier solution is "pgrep {{ PROCESS }}", which does the same thing.  $0.02

Answer (score 6):

Use [`pkill`(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) instead of `grep`+`kill`.

Answer (score 4):

The `killall` command has a wait option that might be useful.

Install psmisc:

```
tasks:
  - apt: pkg=psmisc state=present
```

Then use killall like this:

```
tasks:
  - shell: "killall screen --wait"
    ignore_errors: true # In case there is no process
```

`-w, --wait`:
Wait  for  all  killed  processes to die. killall checks once per second if any of the killed processes still exist and only returns if none are left.

Comment: So elegant compared to the other answers!

Answer (score 4):

After some investigations and struggling with `ansible_linter`, below an alternative way (eg. without use of `ignore_error`)

```yaml
- name: "disable and stop PROCESS"
  service:
    name: PROCESS
    enabled: no
    state: stopped
  tags:
    - stop

- name: "evaluate running PROCESS processes from remote host"
  command: "/usr/bin/pgrep PROCESS"
  register: running_PROCESS
  failed_when: running_PROCESS.rc > 1
  changed_when: 
    - running_PROCESS.rc == 0
  tags:
    - stop

- name: "pkill PROCESS running processes"
  command: "/usr/bin/pkill PROCESS"
  register: kill_PROCESS
  changed_when: kill_PROCESS.rc == 0
  when: running_PROCESS.stdout_lines | length > 0
  tags:
    - stop

- name: "check PROCESS processes"
  wait_for:
    path: "/proc/{{ item }}/status"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ running_PROCESS.stdout_lines }}"
  when: running_PROCESS.stdout_lines | length > 0
  tags:
    - stop

- name: "force kill stuck PROCESS processes"
  command: "/usr/bin/pkill -9 PROCESS"
  register: kill9_PROCESS
  changed_when: kill9_PROCESS.rc == 0
  failed_when: kill9_PROCESS.rc > 1
  when:
    - running_PROCESS.stdout_lines | length > 0
  tags:
    - stop
```

Answer (score 0):

**This Code Worked for me**

```html
- hosts: ubuntu
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Get Apache PIDs
    shell:
      cmd: ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -w apache2 | awk '{print $2}' | awk 'FNR == 1 {print}'
      warn: false
    changed_when: false
    check_mode: false
    register: apache_pids

  - name: Kill running processes
    shell: "kill {{ item }}"
    with_items:
    - "{{ apache_pids.stdout_lines }}"

  - name: Show PIDs
    debug:
      var: apache_pids
```