# Why does Ansible think this shell command has a non-zero return code?

Tags: ansible

I have this recipe:

```yaml
- name: Kill usr/bin/perl -w /usr/share/debconf/frontend
  shell: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - 'pkill -9 -f debconf/frontend || echo'
  changed_when: false # Don't report changed state
```

When I run this on the command line, it returns a 0 exit code thanks to || echo:

```bash
~$ pkill -9 -f debconf/frontend || echo

~$ $?
0
```

However running in Ansible it shows this:

```json
failed: [testhost1] (item=pkill -9 -f debconf/frontend || echo) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "cmd": "pkill -9 -f debconf/frontend || echo", "delta": "0:00:00.132296", "end": "2023-01-13 10:34:11.098765", "item": "sudo pkill -9 -f debconf/frontend || echo", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": -9, "start": "2023-01-13 10:34:10.966469", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a test process via

```bash
perl -MPOSIX -e '$0="test"; pause' &
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Shell task
    shell:
      cmd: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - 'pkill -9 -f test || echo'
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result }}"
```

reproduce the issue. Using instead

```yaml
    with_items:
      - 'pkill -9 -f test'
```

or

```yaml
    with_items:
      - 'kill -9 $(pgrep test) || echo'
```

will execute without an error.

**Links**

- [How can I start a process with any name which does nothing?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174698/266568)
- [How to kill a running process using Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515704/)

**Similar Q&A**

with the same error message

- [Ansible: How force kill process ...?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1084058/)

**Further Reading**

Since it is recommended to use Ansible modules instead of `shell` commands if possible

- [`pids` module – Retrieves process IDs list if the process is running otherwise return empty list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/pids_module.html)

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Get Process ID (PID)
    pids:
      name: test
    register: PID

  - name: Show PID
    debug:
      msg: "{{ PID.pids | first }}"

  - name: Shell task
    shell:
      cmd: "kill -9 {{ PID.pids | first }}"
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result }}"
```

Comment: Thank you, the issue is pkill kills itself in some cases, easily reproducible case is to run this inside of irb (the ruby interpreter): ````pkill -f "anything_here"```` - it will always match and kill a process. So need to grep -v $$ to use pkill, or to take a different approach like you suggested. I added an answer for this how to solve with a 1 liner.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, this is because running pkill from inside of Ansible causes it to kill itself (bug in pkill?)

In any case, a workaround is to do this:

```yaml
  with_items:
    - 'if pgrep -f "debconf/frontend" | grep -v $$; then sudo pkill -9 -f "debconf/frontend"; fi'
```